# How to parse formatted email address into display name and email address (in ColdFusion)?

Tags: coldfusion

Given a formatted email address like these examples:

- `"John" <John@gmail.com>`
- `John Smith <john@smith.com>`
- `john@smith.com (John Smith)`

How do I parse this formatted address into the name and email address parts in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function uses JavaMail to give you an array of [InternetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) objects. You can call getPersonal() to get the name and getAddress() to get the email address.

```
<cfscript>
function getEmailInfo(emailString)
{
    var iAddressClass = "";
    iAddressClass = CreateObject("java", "javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress");
    return iAddressClass.parse(arguments.emailString,true); 
}
</cfscript>
```